# I want the command prompt in the linux terminal to appear on a new line after printing to the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line, printf

After executing the `command` in the bash `terminal` :

```
printf 'A%.0s' {1..20}
```

A string consisting of twenty `"A"` characters will print to the terminal string. What is annoying is that the command prompt will follow directly behind the printed string, which clutters the terminal and looks unsightly, looks like this :

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

That looks terrible. Is it possible to get the command prompt :

```
"ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$"
```

To appear below the printed sequence of characters?

Thank You.

Comment: `printf "$(printf 'A%.0s' {1..20})\n"`

Comment: To be POSIX compliant and not mess up your prompt make sure your final [Line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) terminates with a `<newline>` character (e.g. `'\n'`).

Answer (score 2):

Try bellow command and visit ( http://tpcg.io/5IFLfl ) to execute online :

```
printf "$(printf 'A%.0s' {1..20})\n"
```